# Date showing null or nothing in multiple view type recycler view

Tags: android, json, date, android-recyclerview, multiple-views

Loading a list from Json the model is :

```
message: success
ResponseData": [
    {
        "RecordEntryOn": "2022-01-25T00:00:00",
        "PatientID": 4934,
        "DiscountedAmount": 1380248.0,
        "ClientID": 0,
        "TestType": "Test",
        "TestName": null,
        "fetchingTime": "0001-01-01T00:00:00",
        
    },
{
        "RecordEntryOn": "2022-01-25T00:00:00",
        "PatientID": 1605,
        "DiscountedAmount": 446590.0,
        "ClientID": 0,
        "TestType": "Test",
        "TestName": "Custom package",
        "fetchingTime": "0001-01-01T00:00:00",
        
    },
.....//more entries////
```

Kindly look carefully **the first record represents total revenue for the date** and than the normal list by test name in **first record TestName is null** and than all entires have a test name.
**The first record of list is total revenue for the selected date (selected from calendar)**

I have to display the first entry as

```
**Date : Revenue :**
```

and than the normal list as

```
**Test Name:  Revenue: Patient Count:**
```

I used multiple view to achieve the same everything is working fine but the Date in first entry is not showing, **Revenue is showing correctly** I tried :

```
textview1.setText(String.valueof(response.getRecordyEntryOn());
Result of above is Date : null
```

If I am formatting it as simple date format than it is showing nothing

```
Date :
```

like above

This is how i am defining RecordyEntry in model:

```
@SerializedName("RecordEntryON")
@Expose
private Date record_EntryOn;

public Date getRecord_EntryOn() {
    return record_EntryOn;
}
```

My getItemView in adapter :

```
public int getItemViewType(int position) {


    if ((testResponseList.get(position).getTest_Name()) == null) {
        return revenue_list;
    } else
        return main_list;
}
```

revenue_list is for **Total revenue part where I want to show Revenue and date only**

main_list is the layout where i am showing all other fields

whats the issue here I am not figuring it out kindly help

Answer (score 0):

In your model class, you've used `@SerializedName("RecordEntryON")`. Note the ON in caps, but in the response, the key is "RecordEntryOn", (Small case n).

Try this:

```
@SerializedName("RecordEntryOn")
@Expose
private Date record_EntryOn;

public Date getRecord_EntryOn() {
    return record_EntryOn;
}
```

Edit: Take a look at this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4216767/7453920) for formatting your date.

Comment: yes i figured it out it was a typo.....i changed it to RecordEntryOn and getter also and than no data blank screen whats the issue here i am not getting it

Comment: Your response is a string but you've defined the field as a Date. Have you written a json converter for converting string to date?

Comment: Ralph thanks a lot ...resolved both of your points worked...date was the issue as I have to show date in UI so I am converting it after getting as String